# R : How to deal with "non-unique row.names given" in "predict.sarlm"

Tags: r, prediction, predict

I'm facing an error in R trying to predict a sac model with new data. I'm using the following code:

```
# I've fitted a sac model and now I'm trying to predict for a new dataset:
>newdata = read.csv("location" , header=T , sep=",")
#Calculate the new matrix from this new data:
>cord <- coordinates(newdata[,c("X","Y")])
>k1 <- knn2nb(knearneigh(cord, k=5))
>all.linked <- max(unlist(nbdists(k1, cord)))
>d <- dnearneigh(cord, 0, all.linked)
>dlist <- nbdists(d, coordinates(cord))
>wn = nb2listw(d, glist=dlist, style="W")
#predict:
>prediction = predict.sarlm(sac_model, newdata = newdata, pred.type = "TC", wn )
```

Here's where the problem appears:

> Error in mat2listw(W, row.names = region.id, style = style) : non-unique row.names given

Honestly, I can't see where is the error in the code.